# jQuery banner and Dropdown menu problem

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, drop-down-menu, banner

Hi I have a problem with jQuery banner and dropdown menu. The dropdown menu is behind the jQuery banner slider. Look for a sample [here](http://www.maxline.com.tr/anasayfa)

I tried z-index and position:absolute but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're describing in my browser, which makes me guess that you're using IE7. Is this the case?

Comment: It's reproducable on IE7 and IE8

Comment: it is a problem only with I.E-8..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tested in ie... you do have a problem, but it can be solved with the `z-index` property as [shernshiou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277940/shernshiou) said. you should put this in a css file :

```
#slider{
    z-index : -1;
}
```

**UPDATE**
In ie <= 8, you have to set the z-index for the submenu too (although it should be 0 by default), so, either add a class to every submenu which sets the `z-index` attribute higher than the slider's `z-index`, or you can do it dynamic with jquery :

```
var newZIndex = ($('#slider').css('z-index') || 0) + 10;
$('div[id^=menu_child]').css('z-index',newZIndex);
```

Comment: what version of ie are you using? (i've tested it on ie8 and ie9)

Comment: very very thank you gion_13.. I didnt understand this solution but it fixed problem..

Answer (score 1):

Since i can only verify that in IE, Chrome and Firefox are showing it just fine, we should assume it is the famous IE Z-Index bug.

This can be fixed by giving the parent, that is on the same level (meaning: has the same parent) as the Banner-header a higher z-index than the banner.

In your case that would be the `<tr></tr>` where the navigation is nested

The reason for that is that Internet Explorer considers every nest of elements a new stacking context, which is considered more important than global z-index. 
This leads to elements on the same nesting level having a) a global z-index and b) a relative z-index.

An element one level below can have a global z-index of 5000, but since it is nested one level below it's parent, it will always be considered below his parents siblings.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem viewing that on Google Chrome.

Maybe u can try

```
z-index: -1
```

for those you wanna put at the background.